# Struts2 - How to create a <s:form> for each row in <display:table>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I was trying to show a displaytag table and I wish to map each row on a different s:form.
Each row show all the attributes of my ComputerSystem object and I wish to choose one row and act on the related object.
I tryed to put multiple display:column in one form, but when I load the JSP, I don't find any form tag in the generated source code.

*(I have to use s:form because one of my columns contains a s:doubleselect)*

Any suggestion?

My code:

```
<display:table name="${systemList}" uid="row" pagesize="20" sort="list" requestURI="" >

<display:column title="System ID" property="systemID" />

            ... other columns ...

<s:form action="provision.action" method="post" name="provisionForm%{#attr.row.systemID}">

<display:column title="IP" >
    <s:textfield name="systemList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].ip"  />
</display:column>

<display:column>
    <s:submit type="image" src='image.png' name='submit' />
</display:column>
</s:form>

</display:table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the struts2 iterator tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the  code inside a decorator, obtaining the row object properties, and then use the decorator inside the displaytag.